# byte array to BufferedImage or DecodedImage at Android

Tags: java, android, bufferedimage

I want to use the function below at Android but ImageIO.read function can not be use at Android.

```
    DecodedImage decode(byte[] image) {
        return Exceptions.sneak().get(() -> {
            BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
            if (buffered == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported image format.");
            int width = buffered.getWidth();
            int height = buffered.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            buffered.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
            return new DecodedImage(width, height, pixels);
        });
    }
```

Is there any equivalent function to do this operation in Java for Android?

Comment: What does that byte array contain?

Comment: Further you did not tell what your code does. So how would we know? Which operation?

Comment: simply get a byte[] araay and convert it into DecodedImage or BufferedImage. the content of the byte array is some kind of image but i don't know which type.

Comment: Too vague. Not to the point. We cannot help you.